# window:beforeunload executed on page refresh in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to clear some localStorage variables when browser close or browser tab close. 
It's working totally fine but when I refresh the page it will also clear localstorage variables.

So, **How can we differentiate the page refresh and browser close event in Angular-5 ?**.

My `.ts` file code,

```
import { Renderer, OnInit, AfterViewInit,ElementRef,HostListener} from '@angular/core';

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    localStorage.removeItem('rememberMe');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an appropriate use case for `sessionStorage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: Thank you. I have to do some work around for it but yes sessionStorage suggestion works.